# Piece movement with dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

so i currently have a dictionary which has multiple chess pieces as values and the location as keys. I can currently move each piece according the chess rules but am struggling to make sure piece cannot jump over one another.

This is a piece of my current code that allows the queen to move.

```
QueenRow = int(self.UI_entry2.get()) #mighht not be needed
QueenColumn = int(self.UI_entry3.get())
QueenMoves = self.QueenMoves(QueenRow,QueenColumn)
QueenTuple.append(QueenRow) # Add to list to tuple
QueenTuple.append(QueenColumn) # Add to list to tuple
QueenRowColumn = tuple(QueenTuple) # Tuple the numbers
for piece,position in list(self.pieces.items()): # Get the Key from the values
       if position == QueenRowColumn: # if the tupled numbers equals the key
              print("Piece:",piece,"|","Old Position:",position)   # Print the key and position
              MoveRow = int(self.UI_entry4.get()) #then get the row and column they can move to
              MoveColumn = int(self.UI_entry5.get())
              QueenTuple2.append(MoveRow)
              QueenTuple2.append(MoveColumn)
              TheComparison = tuple(QueenTuple2)
              for TheQueenMoves in QueenMoves: #loop through all the kings moves
                    for a,b in list(self.pieces.items()):    
                      # Move Piece!
                      if TheComparison == TheQueenMoves and TheComparison[0] >= 0 and TheComparison[1] <= 7 and TheComparison[1] >= 0 and TheComparison[0] <= 7:
                      self.placepiece(piece, row = MoveRow, column = MoveColumn)
                      print("Piece:",piece,"|","Current Position:",TheComparison)                                                   print("Possible Moves in current position:",QueenMoves)
                      break
                      del QueenTuple[:]
                      del QueenTuple2[:]
```

(i have not added complete code as it would be too long and alot to read through)

This code allows the Queen to move but does also allows the piece to jump other pieces. Is there any way i can stop this from happening?

Comment: You should build a game board structure: an 8x8 array that contains every piece in its proper position. You can then apply the rules of chess to pieces on that board, taking into account where other pieces are. If you want a dictionary that contains the pieces as keys, fine. Just make the value contain the position of the piece on the board.

Comment: i have an 8x8 array that contains each piece at its proper position, i am using a dictionary "self.pieces" which contains all the pieces and the keys. The only problem im having is applying the rule where piece jumping is not allowed.

Comment: Are you checking each position between the queen's current position and its target position to see if the square is occupied?

Comment: yes, i have also made sure that they cannot occupy the piece if the position is taken but if there is an empty position after the taken position it is possible to move there resulting in jumping the piece.

Comment: You have to check every position between the starting and ending position. So if the queen is moving from row 1 to row 6, you have to check rows 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Comment: @JimMischel Oh no sorry i misread!, i am not checking each positon between the current posotion and its target position!, how would that be done?